# Iterate (loop) through complicated range of numbers using groups to generate Bracket Sheet

Tags: php, loops, iteration

I'm trying to build an algorithm for processing bracket sheet of competitions. I need to go through a range of numbers. For each number there will be the athlete name. Numbers are assigned to athletes randomly but the *number's pairing* must always *stay the same.* There are two groups *odd* and *even*, i.e. A and B.

The only problem that I can't find the proper algorithm to **iterate numbers the exact  way** as follows:

```
Group A:
--------
  1
  17

  9
  25
------
  5
  21

  13
  29
------
  3
  19

  11
  27
------                         
  7
  23

  15
  31


Group B:
--------
  2
  18

  10
  26
------                          
  6
  22

  14
  30
------   
  4
  20

  12
  28
------
  8
  24

  16
  32
```

Could someone please help with advice or example of how to get the output above?

#### EDIT 1:

The example above is the bracket sheet for *32* athletes! Same logic must be applied if you use a sheet for *4,8,16,64* or *128* athletes!

#### EDIT 2:

Let's make it more clear with examples of the sheet for 4 athletes and then the sheet for 16 athletes.

**The sheet for 4 athletes:**

```
Group A:
--------
  1
  3

Group B:
--------
  2
  4
```

**The sheet for 16 athletes:**

```
Group A:
--------
  1
  9

  5
  13
------
  3
  11

  7
  15

Group B:
--------
  2
  10

  6
  14
------                              
  4
  12

  8
  16
```

#### EDIT 3:

The last part, is that I'm planning to have an array with athlete *name* and its *status* in it.
By status I mean that, if the athlete has been a champion previously (strong), then he/she gets *1* for status, if the athlete's previous achievements are not known or minimal (weak), then the status is *0*. It's done that way, so we could separate strongest athletes into different groups and make sure that they will not fight against each other in the first fight but rather meet each other closer to the semi-final or final.

**Example of PHP array:**

```
$participants = array(
array("John", 0),
array("Gagan", 0),
array("Mike Tyson", 1),
array("Gair", 0),
array("Gale", 0),
array("Roy Johnes", 1),
array("Galip", 0),
array("Gallagher", 0),
array("Garett", 0),
array("Nikolai Valuev", 1),
array("Garner", 0),
array("Gary", 0),
array("Gelar", 0),
array("Gershom", 0),
array("Gilby", 0),
array("Gilford", 0)
);
```

From this example we see that those, who have status *1* must be in different groups, i.e. *A* and *B*. But we have only *two groups* of numbers *odd* and *even* and in this example, there are *3 strong athletes*. Thus two of them will be at the same group. The final result must be, that those two strong athletes, that got in the same group, *must not* meet at the very first fight (it means that they will not be on the same pair of numbers and as far away from each other as possible, so they wouldn't meet on the second fight as well).

Then randomly, I'm planning to rearrange the array and send athletes to the bracket sheet - **every time, with different numbers**, **every time, those that have a flag *1* go to different groups and/or never meet at the first fight** and **every time, athletes' names assigned to the same pair of numbers.**

Comment: How are the sub-groups defined? Is sub-group I just 4n+1, while sub-group II is 4n+3? It looks like membership in all your groups is just based on the number modulo 4, does that point you in the right direction?

Comment: Is this just the starting assignments for a bracket sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I finally managed to convert my Tcl code to PHP! I changed some things too:

```
<?php

// Function generating order participants will be placed in array
function getBracket($L) {
    // List will hold insert sequence
    $list = array();
    // Bracket will hold final order of participants
    $bracket = array();
    // The algorithm to generate the insert sequence
    for ($n = 1; $n <= $L; $n += 1) {
        // If 'perfect' number, just put it (Perfect no.s: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc)
        if (substr(log($n)/log(2), -2) == ".0") {
            $list[] = $n;
        // If odd number, stuff...
        } elseif ($n % 2 == 1) {
            $list[] = $list[($n-1)/2];
        // Else even number, stuff...
        } else {
            $list[] = $list[$n/2-1]+$n/2;
        }
    }

    // Insert participant order as per insert sequence
    for ($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($list); $i += 1) {
        $id = $i-1;
        array_splice($bracket, $list[$id], 0, $i);
    }
    return $bracket;
}

// Find number of participants over 'perfect' number if any
function cleanList($L) {
    for ($d = 1; $L > $d; $d += 1) {
        $sq = $L-pow(2,$d);
        if($sq == 0) {break;}
        if($sq < 0) {
            $d = pow(2,$d-1);
            $diff = $L-$d;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $diff;
}

$participants = array(
    array(0, "John", 2),
    array(1, "Gagan", 1),
    array(2, "Mike Tyson", 1),
    array(3, "Gair", 1),
    array(4, "Gale", 0),
    array(5, "Roy Johnes", 0),
    array(6, "Galip", 0),
    array(7, "Gallagher", 0),
    array(8, "Garett", 0),
    array(9, "Nikolai Valuev", 0),
    array(10, "Garner", 1),
    array(11, "Gary", 0),
    array(12, "Gelar", 0),
    array(13, "Gershom", 1),
    array(14, "Gilby", 0),
    array(15, "Gilford", 1),
    array(16, "Arianna", 0)
);

// Extract strength of participant
foreach ($participants as $array) {
    $finorder[] = $array[2];
}
// Sort by strength, strongest first
array_multisort($finorder,SORT_DESC,$participants);

$order = array();
$outside = array();

// Remove participants above 'perfect' number
$remove = cleanList(sizeof($participants));
for ($r = 1; $r <= $remove; $r += 1) {
    $removed = array_shift($participants);
    $outside[] = $removed;
}

// Get corresponding bracket
$res = getBracket(sizeof($participants));
foreach ($res as $n) {
    $order[] = $n;
}

// Align bracket results with participant list
array_multisort($order, $participants);
$participants = array_combine($res, $participants);

echo "The final arrangement of participants\n";
print_r($participants);
print_r($outside);
?>
```

[Codepad demo](http://codepad.org/vqOxieMG)

To get the logic for the order of insertion of elements, I used [this pattern](http://oeis.org/A088370).

Also, since I'm not too familiar with PHP, there might be ways to make some things shorter, but oh well, as long as it works ^^

EDIT: Fixed an issue with first participant sorting and added new ticket numbers. For results without old ticket numbers, see [here](http://codepad.org/op9WcIih).

EDIT2: Managed to move keys into arrays; see [here](http://codepad.org/j1i89fsb).

EDIT3: I thought that 'extra' participants should go outside the bracket. If you want null instead in the bracket, you can use this.

EDIT4: Somehow, PHP versions on codepad broke some stuff... fixing it below and removing initial index...:

```
<?php

    // Function generating order participants will be placed in array
    function getBracket($L) {
        // List will hold insert sequence
        $list = array();
        // Bracket will hold final order of participants
        $bracket = array();
        // The algorithm to generate the insert sequence
        for ($n = 1; $n <= $L; $n += 1) {
            // If 'perfect' number, just put it (Perfect no.s: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc)
            if (int(log($n)/log(2)) || $n == 1) {
                $list[] = $n;
            // If odd number, stuff...
            } elseif ($n % 2 == 1) {
                $list[] = $list[($n-1)/2];
            // Else even number, stuff...
            } else {
                $list[] = $list[$n/2-1]+$n/2;
            }
        }

        // Insert participant order as per insert sequence
        for ($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($list); $i += 1) {
            $id = $list[$i-1]-1;
            array_splice($bracket, $id, 0, $i);
        }
        return $bracket;
    }

    // Find number of participants over 'perfect' number if any
    function cleanList($L) {
        for ($d = 1; $L > $d; $d += 1) {
            $diff = $L-pow(2,$d);
            if($diff == 0) {break;}
            if($diff < 0) {
                $diff = pow(2,$d)-$L;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $diff;
    }

    $participants = array(
        array("John", 2),
        array("Gagan", 1),
        array("Mike Tyson", 1),
        array("Gair", 1),
        array("Gale", 0),
        array("Roy Johnes", 0),
        array("Galip", 0),
        array("Gallagher", 0),
        array("Garett", 0),
        array("Nikolai Valuev", 0),
        array("Garner", 1),
    );

    // Extract strength of participant
    foreach ($participants as $array) {
        $finorder[] = $array[2];
    }
    // Sort by strength, strongest first
    array_multisort($finorder,SORT_DESC,$participants);

    $order = array();

    // Add participants until 'perfect' number
    $add = cleanList(sizeof($participants));
    for ($r = 1; $r <= $add; $r += 1) {
        $participants[] = null;
    }

    // Get corresponding bracket
    $res = getBracket(sizeof($participants));
    // Align bracket results with participant list
    foreach ($res as $n) {
        $order[] = $n;
    }
    array_multisort($order, $participants);
    $participants = array_combine($res, $participants);

    echo "The final arrangement of participants\n";
    print_r($participants);
?>
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/SAWmtU) 
[viper-7](http://viper-7.com/w4MzYM)

Comment: Also, [Tcl version](http://codepad.org/NgdF8RPr) of the code which is much shorter!

Comment: No sure how to automatically randomize (shuffle) the results. Can you as the author recommend something please? Imagine you have competitions in different categories but with the same participants? Then they will always face same opponents (same pairs)!? ::))

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev That sounds like a different question! If there's no restriction on the pairings, then a simple [`shuffle($array);`](http://uk1.php.net/shuffle) sounds ideal.

Comment: I know about `shuffle()` That wouldn't work properly.
But yeah!!!! Solved if finally!! Thanks anyway, my friend!! :D Your code is glorious!

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Uhh I'm not sure how you solved it, I was trying to shuffle participants for those that are of the same strength, but okay it that works!

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Sure. I remember that the initial order of participants can be different, but that the functions in the script consequently sorts them by strength. So that could be you shuffle the original list.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the number of participants is always a power of 2, this piece of code should give you the order you're expecting.

```
function getOrder($numberOfParticipants) {
    $order = array(1, 2);

    for($i = 2; $i < $numberOfParticipants; $i <<= 1) {
        $nextOrder = array();
        foreach($order as $number) {
            $nextOrder[] = $number;
            $nextOrder[] = $number + $i;
        }
        $order = $nextOrder;
    }

    return $order; // which is for instance [1, 17, 9, 25, and so on...] with 32 as argument
}
```

About the way it works, let's take a look at what happens when doubling the number of participants.

```
Participants | Order
           2 | 1   2
           4 | 1   3=1+2   2   4=2+2
           8 | 1   5=1+4   3   7=3+4   2   6=2+4   4   8=4+4
         ... |
           N | 1         X         Y         Z         ...
          2N | 1   1+N   X   X+N   Y   Y+N   Z   Z+N   ...
```

The algorithm I used is the exact same logic. I start with an array containing only `[1, 2]` and `$i` is actually the size of this array. Then I'm computing the next line until I reach the one with the right number of participants.

On a side note: `$i <<= 1` does the same than `$i *= 2`. You can read documentation about [bitwise operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) for further explanations.

---

About *strong* athletes, as you want to keep as much randomness as possible, here is a solution (probably not optimal but that's what I first thought):

1. Make two arrays, one with *strongs* and one with *weaks*
2. If there are no *strongs* or a single one, just shuffle the whole array and go to 8.
3. If there are more *strongs* than *weaks* (dunno if it can happen in your case but better be safe than sorry), shuffle the *strongs* and put the last ones with *weaks* so both arrays are the same size
4. Otherwise, fill up the *strongs* with `null` elements so the array size is a power of 2 then shuffle it
5. Shuffle the weaks
6. Prepare as many groups as they are elements in the *strongs* array and put in each group one of the *strongs* (or none if you have a `null` element) and complete with as many *weaks* as needed
7. Shuffle each group
8. Return the participants, ordered the same way than previous function resulting array

And the corresponding code:

```
function splitStrongsAndWeaks($participants) {
    $strongs = array();
    $weaks = array();

    foreach($participants as $participant) {
        if($participant != null && $participant[1] == 1)
            $strongs[] = $participant;
        else
            $weaks[] = $participant;
    }

    return array($strongs, $weaks);
}

function insertNullValues($elements, $totalNeeded)
{
    $strongsNumber = count($elements);
    if($strongsNumber == $totalNeeded)
        return $elements;
    if($strongsNumber == 1)
    {
        if(mt_rand(0, 1))
            array_unshift($elements, null);
        else
            $elements[] = null;
        return $elements;
    }
    if($strongsNumber & 1)
        $half = ($strongsNumber >> 1) + mt_rand(0, 1);
    else
        $half = $strongsNumber >> 1;
    return array_merge(insertNullValues(array_splice($elements, 0, $half), $totalNeeded >> 1), insertNullValues($elements, $totalNeeded >> 1));
}

function shuffleParticipants($participants, $totalNeeded) {
    list($strongs, $weaks) = splitStrongsAndWeaks($participants);

    // If there are only weaks or a single strong, just shuffle them
    if(count($strongs) < 2) {
        shuffle($participants);
        $participants = insertNullValues($participants, $totalNeeded);
    }
    else {
        shuffle($strongs);

        // If there are more strongs, we need to put some with the weaks
        if(count($strongs) > $totalNeeded / 2) {
            list($strongs, $strongsToWeaks) = array_chunk($strongs, $totalNeeded / 2);
            $weaks = array_merge($weaks, $strongToWeaks);
            $neededGroups = $totalNeeded / 2;
        }
        // Else we need to make sure the number of groups will be a power of 2
        else {
            $neededGroups = 1 << ceil(log(count($strongs), 2));
            if(count($strongs) < $neededGroups)
                $strongs = insertNullValues($strongs, $neededGroups);
        }

        shuffle($weaks);

        // Computing needed non null values in each group
        $neededByGroup = $totalNeeded / $neededGroups;
        $neededNonNull = insertNullValues(array_fill(0, count($participants), 1), $totalNeeded);
        $neededNonNull = array_chunk($neededNonNull, $neededByGroup);
        $neededNonNull = array_map('array_sum', $neededNonNull);

        // Creating groups, putting 0 or 1 strong in each
        $participants = array();            
        foreach($strongs as $strong) {
            $group = array();

            if($strong != null)
                $group[] = $strong;
            $nonNull = array_shift($neededNonNull);
            while(count($group) < $nonNull)
                $group[] = array_shift($weaks);
            while(count($group) < $neededByGroup)
                $group[] = null;

            // Shuffling again each group so you can get for instance 1 -> weak, 17 -> strong
            shuffle($group);
            $participants[] = $group;
        }

        // Flattening to get a 1-dimension array
        $participants = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $participants);
    }

    // Returned array contains participants ordered the same way as getOrder()
    // (eg. with 32 participants, first will have number 1, second number 17 and so on...)
    return $participants;
}
```

If you want the resulting array to have as indexes the number in the bracket, you can simply do:

```
$order = getOrder(count($participants));
$participants = array_combine($order, shuffleParticipants($participants, count($order)));
```

Comment: Very, very nice! The algorithm is correct! It always returns the correct pair of numbers! Could you please provide an example of how I could apply your code to the array of athletes and their status?

Comment: What does `<<= 1` means?

Comment: It's just amazing the way your code works. I never understood `for loops` clearly, though. If you could also provide some comments to your code, it would be very useful for learning! 
Could you please provide an example of how to collaborate your code with the array of participants, based on the status flags described in the question?

Comment: Added some explanations and a solution to work with your statuses, if I understood correctly what you're expecting.

Comment: Newbo, this is as precise as it can be!! At first look and try, all I can say, it's admirable! It woks like expected. Thank you for your amazing explanations and providing best working example ever. Saved me weeks of work. I have to learn much much more. I never used `for loop` really (except ordinary and easy cases) and never bitwise operators. I will integrate your code into my interface and if have more question will come back to you, if you don't mind! So far, if I could accept your answer twice, I would! :D Cheers, my friend!!

Comment: I tested more and found one small issue, that relates to the array_combine function and equal amount of elements in both arrays! Working example: http://ideone.com/v4GRiQ has 16 people and the example when the amount of people is not equal and it fails to work has 19: http://ideone.com/oTBg47
Do you have an idea of what would be the best way to add to `$participants` array just empty key -> values, so the array_combine would get what it needs?

Comment: Indeed, it was working only if the number of participants were a power of 2. So the array is now filled up before shuffling so the `null` values won't always be at the same place (but you may also want `null` values to be better spread so one can't have an almost free bracket). Note that the `splitStrongsAndWeaks` function has also been slightly updated to handle null values.

Comment: Newbo, it works amazingly but only for regular athletes, if I set the value of strong athletes (flag 1) to more than 4, then I get same error  *array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number*. Is it very possible to have more than 4 strong athletes, especially, if there are a lot of participants, like 50 for example!

Comment: If you set the value above 4 but before 8, like 5,6,7 then it returns the error. But if you set the number of strong participants 8 then it's fine. If above 8 then it's always an error!

Comment: Oops, misplaced parenthesis when computing number of groups... This line is now correct `$neededGroups = 1 << ceil(log(count($strongs), 2));`, sorry about that.

Comment: Newbo, we just discovered some fundamental issue, which if you put an array of participants in the particular way, then 4 out of 5 strong athletes go to the group A and only one to group B! Is there a way you could prevent this from happening? Example: http://codepad.org/GL115S8S

Comment: Answer updated so strong athletes are better spread between groups and subgroups. As a bonus, `null` values are now better spread too (when they're needed).

Comment: Thank you, Newbo!! ;) It looks better! I will keep you posted! Take care!!

Comment: Newbo, I am sorry, but I have found one more issue! :) If the number of participants equals 5 and there are 1 strong athlete and 4 weak, then we get array_combine error again? Could you please take a look: http://ideone.com/aRSbh1

Comment: Indeed, and it was failing too if there were no strong athlete at all. Anyway, fixed! (it's around the `if` at line 63 in your ideone)

Comment: Newbo, I'm sorry again but if there are more strong (5) and less weak (4), then array_combine complains again. Also if there are only strong, it fails too. Do you know how to fix it: http://ideone.com/DQbwGd

Comment: Should be fixed by changing line 115 from `if(count($strongs) > count($weaks))` to `if(count($strongs) > $totalNeeded / 2)`

Comment: Newbo, your code works absolutely amazingly without any flaws. Thanks again!! Is this possible to enhance your example, so it would also split, not only strong athletes, but athletes from the same club? I will have club/trainers ids, such as 9982a3a3, or 7222a1b5 or 4322b1c2, so I also would like them not to be at the first fight and BE as FAR away from each other as possible. Splitting strong must remain and work in correspondence. Do you have a clue of how to achieve this? Now strong in your code is kept in `$participant[1]`. The trainers' ids will be kept in `$participant[2]`.

Comment: There is certainly a solution but it's not easy. Moreover, what parameter should be prioritized when you can't respect both conditions (strongness and club)? I'll try to find something though.

Answer (score 1):

This sketchy code might be what you want:

```
<?php

class Pair
{
    public $a;
    public $b;

    function __construct($a, $b) {
        if(($a & 1) != ($b & 1)) 
            throw new Exception('Invalid Pair');
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}

class Competition
{
    public $odd_group = array();
    public $even_group = array();

    function __construct($order) {
        $n = 1 << $order;
        $odd = array();
        $even = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i += 4) {
            $odd[] = $i + 1;
            $odd[] = $i + 3;
            $even[] = $i + 2;
            $even[] = $i + 4;
        }
        shuffle($odd);
        shuffle($even);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($odd); $i += 2) {
            $this->odd_group[] = new Pair($odd[$i], $odd[$i+1]);
            $this->even_group[] = new Pair($even[$i], $even[$i+1]);
        }
        echo "Odd\n";
        for($i = 0; $i < count($this->odd_group); ++$i) {
            $pair = $this->odd_group[$i]; 
            echo "{$pair->a} vs. {$pair->b}\n";
        }
        echo "Even\n";
        for($i = 0; $i < count($this->even_group); ++$i) {
            $pair = $this->even_group[$i]; 
            echo "{$pair->a} vs. {$pair->b}\n";
        }
    }
}

new Competition(5);

?>
```

Comment: Dieter, thank you, it's a very nice try to keep odd and even numbers apart. The only problem that the pair numbers must always maintain the same. In your example it's always different. Look: http://viper-7.com/QkR6PM. Can you try to to make the code work and keep the pair numbers like they ware shown in the example. I will try to update my answer with more details!

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev I leave that for you.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Maybe usort the result.

Comment: usort() will not return the desired `pair of numbers`, right!?